# FirebaseMessaging getToken is not Found what could be the possible solution?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

get token is giving error. working fine in another project

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful())
        {
            String token=task.getResult();
            AppConfig.getInstance().saveFCMDeviceToken(token);
        }
    }
```

Comment: which firebase and play services version you are using?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your build.gradle files, as well as the imports you are using for FirebaseMessaging class. Please respond with @AlexMamo